# Aggregate data from previous column with condition

Tags: r, aggregation

I would like to aggregate both John and Joshua's consumption points, with latest event is the current updated points.

Input data:

```
v1 = c("event1", "event2", "event3")
v2 = c("garlicX", "onionY", "cucumberX")
v3 = c("John", "John", "John")
v4 = c("Joshua", "Joshua", "Joshua")

#John's table points
x1 = c("garlicJohn", "OnionJohn", "CucumberJohn")
x2 = c(1, 2, 3)

#Joshua's table points
x3 = c("garlicJoshua", "OnionJoshua", "CucumberJoshua")
x4 = c(1, 2, 3)


df0 = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)
df1 = data.frame(v1,v2,v3,v4)
```

Desired output:

```
#v5 John's aggregate score
#v6 Joshua's aggregate score

    v1        v2    v3     v4   v5 v6
event1   garlicJohn John Joshua  1  0
event2  onionJoshua John Joshua  1  2
event3 cucumberJohn John Joshua  4  2
```

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stack?

Comment: @sotos He probably got overflowed. On topic: The structure of the data is very confusing. Put some actual data in it.

Comment: Could you explain your v5 and v6 columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while to figure the v5 and v6 columns. Also, I noticed inconsistency in the fact that, x1 and x3 have onion and cucumber starting with Capital, which I changed to small letters. This may not be the best solution but here you go:

```
v1 = c("event1", "event2", "event3")
v2 = c("garlicX", "onionY", "cucumberX")
v3 = c("John", "John", "John")
v4 = c("Joshua", "Joshua", "Joshua")

df1 = data.frame(v1, v2, v3, v4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x1 = c("garlicJohn", "onionJohn", "cucumberJohn")
x2 = c(1, 2, 3)
x3 = c("garlicJoshua", "onionJoshua", "cucumberJoshua")
x4 = c(1, 2, 3)

df0 = data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

forJohn <- 'X'
forJoshua <- 'Y'

for(i in 1:3) {
  if(grepl(forJohn, df1$v2[i])) {
    str1 <- strsplit(df1$v2[i], forJohn)
    str2 <- 'John'
    df1$v2[i] <- paste0(str1, str2)
  } else if(grepl(forJoshua, df1$v2[i])) {
    str1 <- strsplit(df1$v2[i], forJoshua)
    str2 <- 'Joshua'
    df1$v2[i] <- paste0(str1, str2)
  }
}

for(i in 1:3) {
  if(grepl(df1$v2[i], df0$x1[i])) {
    if(i == 1) {
      df1$v5[i] <- i
    } else{
      df1$v5[i] <- i + df1$v5[i-1]
    }
  } else {
    if(i == 1) {
      df1$v5[i] <- 0
    } else {
      df1$v5[i] <- df1$v5[i-1]
    }
  }
}

for(i in 1:3) {
  if(grepl(df1$v2[i], df0$x3[i])) {
    if(i == 1) {
      df1$v6[i] <- i
    } else{
      df1$v6[i] <- i + df1$v6[i-1]
    }
  } else {
    if(i == 1) {
      df1$v6[i] <- 0
    } else {
      df1$v6[i] <- df1$v6[i-1]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
      v1           v2   v3     v4 v5 v6
1 event1   garlicJohn John Joshua  1  0
2 event2  onionJoshua John Joshua  1  2
3 event3 cucumberJohn John Joshua  4  2
```

EDIT: If anyone is wondering how v5 and v6 were calculated. Here is the explanation.

garlicJohn and garlicJoshua are mapped to 1, similarly, onionJohn, onionJosha, cucumberJohn and cucumberJoshua are mapped to 2, 2, 3, and 3 respectively.

Now, from v2 column in df1 we need to check what the value is from df0 dataframe. garlicJohn corresponds to 1. v5 needs to aggregate values based on John whereas v6 based on Joshua. Therefore, garlicJohn would be 1 for v5 and 0 for v6. We now have onionJosha, which would mean v5 second row stays as such while v6 second row becomes 2. For the final row, in v5, we add the current mapped value to the value from previous index (3 + 1), while v6 remains the same.